# Why rotation larger than 90 or smaller than 0 makes skybox reverse

Tags: javascript, webgl

```
var rotation = Math.PI / 2
var cameraPosition = [0, Math.cos(rotation), Math.sin(rotation)];
```

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b908gvnc/

Try to drag the range, when the range's value is larger than 90, the skybox map will be reverse.

But why? And is there any solution of the problem?

Comment: If 0° is looking straight ahead and 90° is looking at your feet, then 180° *has to be* looking right behind you. Where else would it be? Think of rotating your head downwards. At one point you'll end up looking behind you and upside down until you rotate all the way back to looking ahead of you. Try rotating around a different axis and you'll find something that suits you better.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I got it! It's easy to understand. Thank you. It would be better if you can explain how to solve it